# Compare JSON structure in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have two json objects as below:

```
obj1= [ { "id": 4, "userId": "abc", "firstName": "abc", "lastName": "abc", "email": "abc@abc.it", "prefers" : [{"breakfast" : "bread" , "lunch" : "non-veg"}] } ]

obj2= [ { "id": 5, "userId": "def", "firstName": "def", "lastName": "def", "email": "def@def.it", "prefers" : [{"breakfast" : "egg" , "lunch" : "veg"}] } ]
```

Given these to objects i have to validate object2 has the same keys as in object1

`diff(obj1,obj2)` should give me missing keys

Comment: You need to create a recursive method to collect the all keys and then use `Array#-` method.

Answer (score 0):

use `keys` to return an array of keys of the hash and then subtract them

```
obj1[0].keys - obj2[0].keys
# => array of missing keys
```

Comment: Thanks for responing i have done JSON.parse for both the objects in ruby and it returns array and is not an object

Comment: shouldn't  it be obj1[0].keys, since obj1 and obj2 are arrays?

Comment: @user1896766 are you looking to compare keys that are within the values as well e.g. `lunch`?

Answer (score 0):

This [Ruby JSON comparator](https://gist.github.com/ke4roh/348afe4a793d7d281071) will show you how to do it.  It is designed to compare the two objects and return true if they're same, but from that you can devise a more complicated return value based on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want true/false validation that the keys of both objects match, you can do:

```
object1.keys && object2.keys == object1.keys
```

That will give you a validation of matching or not.